# Faster Multiplication of double Array values

Tags: c#, arrays, multiplication

Hello I have a one dimensional array which represents a two dimensional array. Based on the position of each value will determine the coefficient it is multiplied by.

At the moment I iterate over each value in a for loop, multiply by the correct coefficient and then store the product in another array.

**MultiplyEachValue.cs**

```
internal double[] MultiplyEachValue(double[] oneDimArray, int width, int height, Alignment coeffs)
{
    var toReturn = new double[oneDimArray.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < oneDimArray.Length; i++)
    {
        double curVal;
        if(isEvenPos(i, width, height) == true)
        {
            curVal = coeffs.Small * oneDimArray[i];
        }
        else if (isOddPos(i, 4, 2) == true)
        {
            curVal = coeffs.Large * oneDimArray[i];
        }
        else if (isOppoPos(i, 4, 2) == true)
        {
            curVal = coeffs.Medium * oneDimArray[i];
        }
        else
        {
            curVal = 1;
        }
        toReturn[i] = curVal;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

**Any idea how I can make it faster?** 
I have heard of things like dot multiplication but I do not know if it can be applied here. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!!!

Comment: what you mean by *faster* exactly?

Comment: What do `isOddPos` `isEvenPos` and `isOppoPos` do, and what is the reason for the arguments of 4 and 2?

Comment: These methods simply determine where the elements would be in an 2-d array. If they are in an even col and even row, odd column and odd row, or inverse. Thats it

Comment: What I mean by faster is that it needs to scale better. With oneDimArray of size x it completes in 20ms. I want to reduce that time with the same x size array

Comment: It should be possible to predict ahead of time where the even/odd positions are, then you won't have to test for them.

Comment: For every element you have up to 3 method calls to chose proper if branch! Make one function that return type of element position. Call it once and then do proper calculation.

Comment: Or, if it need some complex calculation to obtain element type, even break it into 4 loops over every subsets (which corresponds to every `if` branch you have) -> it eliminates repeating type understanding at all.

Comment: All great feedback. Thanks guys!

Comment: `[is*Pos() tell whether row&col are both even, both odd, or opposed]`: please put information like this *in the question*, and clarify "the `4 and 2`-issue" John Wu already mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the app with profiling, ideally with a large input so that it takes longer. Then identify hotspots, then review those to see if they can be improved.

Also be aware that elapsed execution time and CPU consumed time are different things too. Are you seeking to reduce CPU cost or elapsed time?

You should also order your if/else ladder to test for the most common scenario first, for example if most of the data ends up in the last if test, then making that check the first check will improve things.

Having said that, the code looks easy to parallelize and on a multi-core machine you could - in principle - see an 'n' factor speed up with 'n' cores if you parallelize the loop.

Answer (score 1):

(This problem seems well suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)
Having a single (single dimension) array doesn't mean nested loops aren't advantageous.
Assuming "row order" (and keeping things I'd rather do differently for recognition value):

```
double[] MultiplyEachValue(double[] oneDimArray,
    int width, int height, Alignment coeffs)
{
    var toReturn = new double[oneDimArray.length];
    const double
        even = coeffs.Small,
        opposed = coeffs.Medium,
        odd = coeffs.Large;
    for (int i = 0, r = 0 ; r < height ; r++) {
        for (int c = 1 ; c < width ; c += 2) {
            toReturn[i] = even * oneDimArray[i]; i++;
            toReturn[i] = opposed * oneDimArray[i]; i++;
        }
        if (1 == (1 & width)) {
            toReturn[i] = even * oneDimArray[i]; i++;
        }
        if (height <= ++r)
            return toReturn;
        for (int c = 1 ; c < width ; c += 2) {
            toReturn[i] = opposed * oneDimArray[i]; i++;
            toReturn[i] = odd * oneDimArray[i]; i++;
        }
        if (1 == (1 & width)) {
            toReturn[i] = opposed * oneDimArray[i]; i++;
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

(Conceivably, `1 & width` doesn't change much during any given call of `MultiplyEachValue()`, so it could be evaluated once and for all - you could even have two versions of the outer loop lust to avoid checking for an odd number of columns in every single row. Or copy "the even row handling" just like shown for "even column handling".)
(The code is "back adapted" from a sloppy POP in Java - I keep forgetting about online C# playgrounds.)